# 20.04 firefox snap - downloads can't be opened nor can containing folder

Tags: firefox, 20.04, snap, downloads

When I download a file, if I try to open it or it's containing folder all I get is the Launch Application dialog asking me to choose an application. No applications are listed for me to choose from and if I select 'Choose other Application' it only lets me choose my own applications, not system ones (e.g. nautilus). This is a change from 18.04 which worked as expected. I assume its some kind of security/privilege issue but have no idea what to do about it.
This is the snap version of firefox:

```
rod@Isildur:~$ apt policy firefox
firefox:
  Installed: 76.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
  Candidate: 76.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 76.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     75.0+build3-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
rod@Isildur:~$ snap list | grep -i firefox
firefox             76.0-2                      355   latest/stable  mozilla*      -
```

Checked it out today with 76.0.1 and its still the same.
I've removed the snap and it now works properly.

If anyone else wants to remove the snap I suggest **snap remove --purge firefox** to avoid making a huge snapshot.

Beware though, this will lose your open tabs, bookmarks, history. The snap seems a bit of a mess really.

Comment: Is this Firefox a snap application? Please **[edit]**  your question with the outputs of the following two commands in Terminal: `apt policy firefox` and `snap list | grep -i firefox`

Comment: That seems to be a problem with the snap version only. As a workaround I'd suggest you use the DEB version. You can uninstall the snap version with `snap remove firefox`.

Comment: Do you know if it has been reported as a bug?

Comment: This is still not working ? How is ubuntu going 1 step forward 2 steps back ?? Ever since 2008 it has just been getting worse....

Answer (score 0):

If stable firefox version does not work as expected and you need a snap version, you could try a [different](https://snapcraft.io/firefox) installation channel:

```
sudo snap install firefox --beta
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have installed both the deb package of Firefox, and the snap package of Firefox. When you launch Firefox, you end up running the snap package that has some security features relating to file associations. Those are being resolved, and probably it is not ready yet.

Therefore, uninstall Firefox from the Snap Store, and you will be able to launch the deb package of Firefox that does not have these issues.